# How do i cut a username from a file while still showing processes?

Tags: sorting, grep, cut

My teacher provided us with a file called myProcesses that has the processes from many people, my objective is to cut out all processes for a user as defined by a variable, how can i achieve this?

Here are my variables so far.
`command=grep`
`user=mhalprin`
`file=myProcesses`

With this, i am able to cut all processes that include "mhalprin" somewhere in the myProcesses file, but one of those include the "root" user because it has "mhalprin" at the end, how can i cut that out of this command?
[Screen shot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgPHI.png)

Comment: Don't use `grep` use `awk` and match on a specific field?

Comment: Good idea, but im unfamiliar with Awk, ill have to do some searching on how i can user this to my advantage, thanks!

Comment: found the awk command.
`awk '$3 == "mhalprin"' myProcesses

But now i cant figure out a way to use my variable in this command..

Comment: [How to use shell variables in awk script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/258523)

Comment: Better [edit] your question showing some sample input, desired output and what you tried. No screenshots. Currently it is quite confusing.